# Spring Batch one time data load operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We are working on a Spring Batch application where a Job needs to process multiple files.For these files to be processed,certain data needs to be loaded at the start as the processing of the files would depend on this data.As we would like this data to be loaded only once,what is the best approach-Load the data once using a Singleton pattern or use a cache like ehCache or use Spring Batch's meta tables to store the information afer the first time load.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to 'load one-time' data in `JobListener.BeforeJob` or if that data depends on processed items I do a progressive load.
I do that because 'one-time data' are usually huge and store then into `ExecutionContext` (SB metadata table) is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks @LucaBassoRicci

Comment: What do you mean by a Progressive Load?

Comment: I meant to load external data during job processing (usually you need during item processing) one by one (you can use a cache, if you want); the point is not to store items into execution context